# Touch not working on list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I am using touch event on LinearLayout in which there is a list view(Its a child). When I touch on list view part touch event does not gets called. below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llFavourite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Loading"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:focusable="true">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My animation:

```
final Animation slidedown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down_half);
    llFavourite.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MidnightMainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            llFavourite.startAnimation(slidedown);
            inflateFavouriteLayout(MODE_REFRESH);
        }
    });
```

but when I click on layout part event gets called. Is there any property which i should enable or disable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> android:focusable="false"

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

doesn't work for ImageButton.

In your layout xml, add this property to root layout

> android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: It's not working.It only works if I remove progress bar from the layout.I want that when user pulls down the list to refresh then list become invisible and this progress bar is shown. and again after refreshing list become visible and progress bar invisible.

Answer (score 0):

from your calling class add

```
     ListView lView =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        Log.i(position);

    }

});
```